# Controller design for likable/followable objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models, User, Product, Like. That is, a user can (un)like a product...

I wonder what would be best practice to design controller and models.

1. Creating likes_controller and process create/destroy actions
2. Creating like/unlike actions inside products_controller
3. or something else.

Second question; into which model should I put methods such as "retrieve_likes," "liked?," or "like! /unlike!"

Edit: I found this excellent gem through TeachMeToCode.com, https://github.com/cavneb/make_flaggable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done both option 1 and 2 before and they've both worked fine. It really depends on your philosophy and how much of the REST kool-aid you've drank. Go with #1 to be RESTful.  I've found sticking to a more RESTful interface makes testing seem a bit cleaner and the code, in general, seem a bit cleaner. At the expense, however, of having way more files.

As for the models, you could create a Likable module which contains the methods for "liked?", etc...  Then you can include this module in any of the models which need them.  Take a look at some gems that extend ActiveRecord models to get an idea how to do that.

Comment: Well, I managed to succeed doing the second option and works charming even with ajax. I added member routes like and unlike. Yet I am having problem with routes when I try to convert it to the first option. I made it nested into products inside routes. How can I make it behave like member object, such as  products/:id/(un)like rather than products/:id/likes.

Answer (score 0):

You could have 3 tables:

```
users: user_id, name, like_id
products: product_id, info, like_id
likes: like_id, user_id, product_id
```

In your `User` model:

```
has_many :likes
```

In your `Product` model:

```
has_many :likes
```

In your `Like` model:

```
belongs_to product
belongs_to user
```

This would allow you to do things like call `<%= @product.likes.count %>` for a count of the number of times something was liked.

Or in the users controller: `@liked_products = User.likes.map(&:product)`.

To create links that populate the `likes` table, you will need to make a likes controller with the `add_like` and `remove_like` methods.

You may also need to learn about something called "nested routing" to get it all working.

Comment: Well, well, well. Tho my question was chiefly about controller design, I appreciate your endeavor to help me with the model design. Yet, I do not exactly understand why you need to create like_id field for both user and products. (Perhaps for mapping liked products by user?). Btw, I guess I need to check whether current_user.has_liked?(product) inside User model. Tx.